# не понимаю результат работы параллельной программы

Tags: c++, многопоточность

есть такой импровизированный участок кода

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <thread>

void print_string(const std::string message)
{
  std::cout << message;
}

int main()
{
  std::thread t1(print_string, "hello ");
  t1.detach();
  std::vector<int> nums(2000);
  for (int i = 0;i < nums.size();++i) {
    nums[i] = rand();
  }
  sort(nums.begin(), nums.end());
  std::cout << "world!\n";
  return 0;
}
```

результаты работы:
1) hello world! -- такой исход мне понятен

не понятны такие исходы: 
2) world! 
3) world!
hello

то есть здесь 2000 элементов инициализировались и отсортировались и еще произошел вывод "world!" быстрее чем вывело "hello "? почему такое происходит?

Comment: потому что потоки друг от друга независимы

Comment: потому что создание потока - не такая уж и простая задача. А заполнение/сортировка хоть и выглядят страшно, могут быть выброшены компилятором, так как ничего не делают

Comment: Раз межпоточная синхронизация отсутствует, то и отрабатывать потоки могут в любом порядки. Даже если вместо цикла поставить задержку на 1 час, то это не будет означать, что "hello " *должно* быть выведенно раньше, чем "world".

Comment: @KoVadim да я что то тоже все таки склоняюсь к тому что, создание потока дольше произошло чем все остальные операции в master потоке

Comment: а может просто закешировалось

Comment: @KoVadim да все таки тяжеловесное создание потока сказалось, 100млн элементов сортирую и всегда "hello " первее выводит

Comment: Ну никак на VC++ 2017 добиться `word` до `hello` не удалось...

Comment: @Harry попробуйте в релизе посмотреть, а и у меня 19 версия если что

Comment: Да я только в релизе такие вещи (прогон из ruSO), в командной строке и делаю...

Answer (score 0):

Есть такое понятие, как буфер потока. Пока вы не сделаете `cout.flush();` строку `'hello '` - не увидите.

Стандарт :

> Concurrent access to a stream object (27.8, 27.9), stream buffer
>   object (27.6), or C Library stream (27.9.2) by multiple threads may
>   result in a data race (1.10) unless otherwise specified (27.4). [
>   Note: Data races result in undefined behavior (1.10). — end note ]
>
> Concurrent access to a synchronized (27.5.3.4) standard iostream
>   object’s formatted and unformatted input (27.7.2.1) and output
>   (27.7.3.1) functions or a standard C stream by multiple threads shall
>   not result in a data race (1.10). [ Note: Users must still synchronize
>   concurrent use of these objects and streams by multiple threads if
>   they wish to avoid interleaved characters. — end note ]

Перевод :

> Одновременный доступ к объекту потока (27.8, 27.9), объекту буфера
>   потока (27.6) или потоку библиотеки C (27.9.2) несколькими потоками
>   может привести к гонке данных (1.10), если не указано иное (27.4).
>   [Примечание: гонки данных приводят к неопределенному поведению (1.10).
>   - конец примечания]
>
> Одновременный доступ к синхронизированным (27.5.3.4) стандартным
>   функциям входного (27.7.2.1) и выходного (27.7.3.1) ввода или вывода
>   (27.7.3.1) стандартного объекта iostream или стандартному потоку C
>   несколькими потоками не должен приводить к гонке данных (1.10).
>   [Примечание: пользователи по-прежнему должны синхронизировать
>   одновременное использование этих объектов и потоков несколькими
>   потоками, если они хотят избежать чередования символов. - конец
>   примечания]

Так работает чётко :

```
void print_string(const std::string message)
{
  std::cout << message;
  std::cout.flush();
}
```

Comment: делал flush, оказалось значит что даже в буфер не попадал "hello" так как поток не успевал создаться и выполнить свою полезную работу

Comment: Всё может быть. Вы не только синхронизировали поток вывода, но ещё и не сделали метку, что поток закончил работы. `std::atomic<bool> finished{false}; finished=true;` @Ildar

Comment: Я проверил. Всегда выводит `'hello world!'`.